# LibreOffice font styles (bold, semibold, condensed, etc)

Tags: linux, fonts, libreoffice, styles, bug

I have switched to Linux but it don't support MS Office, so I found the alternative - LibreOffice.
I need to open foreign presentations or documents that have fonts like "Bahnschrift SemiCondensed", but LibreOffice can't show and reproduce this font
[Screenshot: font not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuSFU.png)

But in other program I can see this font!
[Screenshot: font available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVE6R.png)

Is there a solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem: LibO gets confused when a font offers many weights or shapes. Try to remove the ones you don't need and see if the needed one show up. For further info see also:

[Fonts missing in Linux (though available to other software)](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/173637/fonts-missing-in-linux-though-available-to-other-software/)

You know, when documents are sent from one computer to the next or opened on the same computer in a different operating system, these documents may not look the same unless all the fonts used in the document are available on the other computer or operating system.

Some hints [Dealing with missing fonts](https://design.blog.documentfoundation.org/2016/10/21/dealing-with-missing-fonts/)

Search on Ask Ubuntu for your needs too like e.g. [Why are most of my fonts missing from LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071373/why-are-most-of-my-fonts-missing-from-libreoffice).